# Sending a dictionary from Watch to App - WatchConnectivity

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, watchkit

I have a dictionary

```
dict = [Int : Bool]
```

and i was wondering if there is a simple way to send it to **iPhone** from **watch** and vice-versa through interactive messaging in WatchConnectivity framework?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so like this:

```
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        let session = WCSession.default
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }

    let dict = [Int : bool]
    let message = ["message" : dict]
    WCSession.default.sendMessage(message,
        replyHandler: { (reply) -> Void in
        },
        errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        }
    )
```

Comment: I think you should add `activateSession()`, or `WCSession` won't work

Answer (score 0):

In your `watchkit extention` write following code :

```
func getDataFromParentApp(image: String) {
    let dictionary = ["Desired Word":image]
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(dictionary) {
        (replyInfo, error) -> Void in
    }
```

And in the `AppDelegate` write following one :

```
func application(application: UIApplication!,
    handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
    reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
        getImageForWordThatRhymesWithDat(userInfo, reply)
}
```

You can refer this [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/watchKit-extensions-communicating-with-your-parent-application/).

Comment: openParentApplication was deprecated. I specifically noted that the question is related to WatchConnectivity framework.